# Mysterious CPU Activity in MS SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I am looking at the activity monitor in MS SQL Management Studio 2005, and I see an entry from a login that I created, and it's using the tempdb, and the last command is always "SELECT INTO". And everytime I hit "Refresh" in activity monitor, that entry's "CPU" column goes up by like 60. The "program" of that activity is "MS SQL Management Studio."

I tried to kill that process, but it won't allow me, saying "cannot be killed". I disconnect from the database and reconnect, and that process is still there.

Is it gonna eventually crash my SQL Server because of continous activity? And is anyone familiar with this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Dude, that's you running either Activity Monitor or SP_WHO[2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is you.  More specifically SSMS.  Typically it will `SELECT INTO` some temp table (something it calls, will do it actually) in order to get data from the server to display to you.  Open another SSMS and you should see two of them.

Comment: Typically the SELECT INTO is very quick and non-blocking.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely normal. The Select Into is selecting data into a temp table to show you what you see in the Activity Monitor. No need to panic. It will not crash your SQL Server.

Raj

Comment: Whoever down voted me for this answer - though not visible here - please at least be man enough to explain yourself.